# How to show the DateTime table?

Tags: python, django

### im making a webapp, im making a DateTime table, I have done this before but without any problem

forms.py

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
input_type = 'date'

class HomeworkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Homework
        Widgets = {'due':DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'})}
        fields = ['subject','title','description','due','is_finished']
```

models.py

```
class Homework(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    due = models.DateTimeField()
    is_finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
def homework(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = HomeworkForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            finished = request.POST['is_finished']
            if finished == 'on':
                finished = True
            else:
                finished = False
        except:
            finished = False

        homework = Homework(
            user = request.user ,
            subject = request.POST['subject'],
            title = request.POST['title'],
            description = request.POST['description'],
            due = request.POST['due'],
            is_finished = finished
        )
        homework.save()
        messages.success(request,f'Homework Added from {request.user.username}!!')
else:
    form = HomeworkForm()
homework = Homework.objects.filter(user=request.user)
if len(homework) == 0:
    homework_done = True
else:
    homework_done = False
context = {
    'homeworks':homework,
    'homeworks_done':homework_done,
    'form':form,
    }
return render(request,'dashboard/homework.html', context)
```

---

Ive used many ways to show the DateTime table in 'due' , where i can choose date from something like a calendar but i still got nothing and when i input a date myself f.e(2020-2-1)i see an error telling that the date form is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `TimeStampedModel`
your code will be:

```
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel

class Homework(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    due = models.DateTimeField()
    is_finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and then just run `makemigration` and `migrate`
you will have two fields in your model, **created** & **modified** you can use them.

Answer (score 1):

I am using something like:

```
widgets = {
    'datetime_field': DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%d'+'T'+'%H:%M', attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}),
    'date_field': DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%d', attrs={'type': 'date'}),
    }
```